# Variance Analysis with SQL and Tableau

Tags: mysql, sql, tableau-api

Here is the situation. Right now we have two databases. Database A is used by my department. We input data into various tables (web based front end) on a quarterly basis. Once that activity is complete, all that data is pushed into corresponding tables on Database B (which is a repository for the entire business). I'm not involved with pushing this data from Database A to Database B, and I'm a little fuzzy how so much variance is happening in the first place, however, I have been tasked with improving the variance analysis activities that happen afterwards. Some IT person somewhere at some point set up a procedure that runs and dumps data in a variance analysis table (which is then extracted into an excel sheet) and is set up like this:

**CRAPPY TABLE**

`ID    A.Col A     B.Col A     Flag Col A     A.Col B     B.Col B     Flag Col B 
1      Yellow      Yellow          0           5          5             0
2      Yellow      Green           1           3          2             1
3      Blue        Blue            0           7          7             0
4      Red         Blue            1           4          2             1
5      Yellow      Red             1           1          3             1`

One of the tables we are trying to perform variance analysis on has 40 columns, and the resulting variance analysis table has 120+ columns in it: the column in database a, the column in database b, and the flag column that indicates if there is a variance between the two columns (0 if there is no variance, 1 if there is a variance).

As you can imagine, importing this extract into Tableau from the Excel file is very limiting in terms of what visualizations I can pull off. I have access to the backend of both database A and database B, and I can actually connect Tableau directly to the tables in their respective databases (rather than relying on the excel extract or the table the excel extract is coming from) and use Custom SQL to pull the data in how I want, and am hoping there is a way to use SQL to achieve a different table layout, more like this:

**BETTER TABLE**

`ID      Flag Name     Value A     Value B
2        Flag A        Yellow      Green
2        Flag B        3           2
4        Flag A        Red         Blue
4        Flag B        4           2
5        Flag A        Yellow      Red
5        Flag B        1           3`

Ideally, as above, this new layout would be able to exclude any rows/columns where there isn't a variance, but if that can't be achieved, I would be happy to have an additional column called 'Flag Value' and just filter out the zero's.

So, how would I write a select statement in SQL to turn this:

`Database A`

`ID     Col A     Col B
1      Yellow     5
2      Yellow     3
3      Blue       7
4      Red        4
5      Yellow     1`

`Database B`

`ID     Col A     Col B
1       Yellow    5
2       Green     2
3       Blue      7
4       Blue      2
5       Red       3`

Into the **BETTER TABLE** so I can actually use this data in a meaningful way in Tableau? Thank you mucho for your help, Stack Overflow SQL experts!

Comment: Ok, in doing more research, it looks like I might need to do an "unpivot" type function, but I'm unsure how I would go about doing that with two different tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be to use a nested query containing a union. You can probably achieve this using pivot/unpivot, although I often find that syntax cumbersome, especially when the tables have many columns.

Instead try something like:

**MS SQL Server**

```
SELECT a.ID, [Flag Name], [Value A], [Value B]
FROM (SELECT a.ID
          , [Flag Name] = CASE WHEN a.ColA != b.ColA THEN 'Flag A' ELSE NULL END
          , a.ColA [Value A]
          , b.ColA [Value B]
    FROM TableA a
    JOIN TableB b on a.ID = b.ID
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT b.ID
         , [Flag Name] = CASE WHEN a.ColB != b.ColB THEN 'Flag B' ELSE NULL END
         , CAST(a.ColB AS VARCHAR(1)) [Value A]
         , CAST(b.ColB AS Varchar(1)) [Value B]
    FROM TableA a
    JOIN TableB b on a.ID = b.ID
) a 
WHERE [Value A] != [Value B]
ORDER BY ID
```

**MySQL**

```
SELECT a.ID, `Flag Name`, `Value A`, `Value B`
FROM (SELECT a.ID
          , CASE WHEN a.ColA != b.ColA THEN 'Flag A' ELSE NULL END AS`Flag Name`
          , a.ColA `Value A`
          , b.ColA `Value B`
    FROM TableA a
    JOIN TableB b on a.ID = b.ID
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT b.ID
         , CASE WHEN a.ColB != b.ColB THEN 'Flag B' ELSE NULL END AS `Flag Name` 
         , CAST(a.ColB AS CHAR(1)) `Value A`
         , CAST(b.ColB AS CHAR(1)) `Value B`
    FROM TableA a
    JOIN TableB b on a.ID = b.ID
) a 
WHERE `Value A` != `Value B`
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: This looks very promising! Going to try it out now and will come check as answered asap.

Comment: Ok, I'm operating in MySQL. Not sure if that makes a difference in syntax or not. But the only change I made to your script is to change `TableA` and `TableB` to `table_a` and `table_b`, and also changed `ColA` and `ColB` to `COL_A` and `COL_B`. I kept the alias names the same (a, b) for the tables. I'm getting an error: 1 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[Flag Name], [Value A], [Value B]
FROM (SELECT a.ID
          , [Flag Name] = ' at line 1 SQL.sql 1 1

Comment: Yes, it makes a difference. My apologies, I assumed MS SQL Server. Unfortunately I'm not well versed in MySQL, so making the necessary syntax edits will take some time. Go ahead and add tag for MySQL to post and perhaps somebody else with more MySQL experience will see the post.

Comment: Ok, no worries. Funny - Database A is Oracle, Database B is Postgre, and I'm going to use an internal company tool to replicate the tables in my own MySQL server database, but I am still a complete novice at SQL so I appreciate your help! The idea is solid!

Comment: Try Edited code for MySQL - See if that throws an error. If so, I'm afraid I cant help you and will remove the answer.

Comment: Getting close! This error seems like it won't be a huge deal to figure out: 1 Unknown column 'Flag Name' in 'field list'

Comment: I think your best bet would be to remove the spaces from your column names and replace with an underscore or just "FlagName"

Comment: the fix was simple - instead of `Flag Name` = CASE WHEN a.ColA != b.ColA THEN 'Flag A' ELSE NULL END, it needed to be written as CASE WHEN a.ColA != b.ColA THEN 'Flag A' ELSE NULL END AS `Flag Name`